# How to Compare DateFormat to a String array

Tags: java, android

I have the following date format: `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE, LLLL d");`
and the following String array:

```
String[] Days = {
        "Tuesday, January 1",
        "Monday, January 21",
        "Sunday, February 10",
        "Tuesday, February 12",
        "Wednesday, February 13",
        "Monday, February 18",
        "Sunday, February 24",
        "Tuesday, March 26",
        "Wednesday, March 27",
        "Thursday, March 28",
        "Friday, March 29",
        "Monday, April 1",
        "Tuesday, April 2",
        "Thursday, May 2",
        "Friday, May 3",
        "Thursday, May 9",
        "Wednesday, May 15",
        "Thursday, May 16",
        "Monday, May 27",
        "Thursday, July 4",
        "Wednesday, August 7",
        "Thursday, August 8",
        "Friday, August 9",
        "Thursday, August 15",
        "Monday, September 2",
        "Thursday, September 5",
        "Friday, September 6",
        "Saturday, September 14",
        "Thursday, September 19",
        "Friday, September 20",
        "Thursday, September 26",
        "Friday, September 27",
        "Monday, October 14",
        "Tuesday, October 15",
        "Wednesday, October 16",
        "Thursday, October 17",
        "Friday, November 1",
        "Sunday, November 3",
        "Tuesday, November 5",
        "Monday, November 11",
        "Thursday, November 28",
        "Sunday, December 8",
        "Wednesday, December 25"
};
```

How do I do a comparison so let's say `df` = `Friday, September 27` it will be true as the String `Days` has a value "Friday, September 27" in the array.

I did the following but my widget FC:

```
    for (int j=0; j<=suspendedDates.length;j++) {
        if (df.format(new Date()) == suspendedDates[j]) {
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvParkStatus, "Parking Suspended");
        }
        else {
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvParkStatus, "Parking Not Suspended");
        }
    }
```

Comment: So do you want to do an equality comparison against one of the array elements or do you want to see if the String array contains a given date?

Comment: The second option, go through the entire String array to see if the date is listed there.

Comment: Why do you have an array of date strings? If it's not too cumbersome, I'd convert those strings (there's not too many of them) into proper date objects, either using the built-in Date class, or by using a date library like Joda-Time (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Comment: To go through entire String array, iterate through the array's indices using a for loop or similar, and compare each element to the formatted Date object's toString() output. But I still think it would be easier to convert your reference array from Strings to Dates.

Comment: I am creating a widget which shows the user today's date and tells them by comparing those string to see if the parking is suspended or not for that day.

Comment: I fully agree with @StockB You should really use a `Date` class instead of using the String representation of the dates.

Comment: I will implement it. Thanks for the informative feedback :) (Is it for speed or security or standard?)

Comment: It's just good object-oriented design. A Date ojbect is a far better representation of your object (a date in time) than a string of characters. For one, a good Date class will not allow invalid dates (e.g. February 30) and isn't sensitive to different display formats. 

From a data structures perspective, your data (e.g. the actual date) should be seperated from the view, which is the representation of your data (e.g. the string "Tuesday, January 1").

A string of "Tues., Jan. 1" will not match "Tuesday, January 1", but a good Date class will recognize that they are, in fact, the same date.

Comment: Also, a Date class could get the day of the week for a particular date, so you don't mess up "Monday, January 1" and "Tuesday, January 1". A date class would allow you to detect or prevent such errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should does the trick :

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d", Locale.US);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(Days).contains(df.format(Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US).getTime())));
```

Output :

> True

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you'd need a **DateFormatter** since it looks like you have a String and an array of Strings as inputs. Just check for the String:

```
Arrays.asList(Days).contains("Friday, September 27");
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer so you get credit :) Thanks for the help.